# Problem at changing the Activity, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Hi Im coding an Math App for fun and have som problems with it in Kotlin, i treid search in the Internet but couldnt find anything,

I have this two Activitys

```
class VorlageTarif(var A: Double, var G: Double) : AppCompatActivity() ,  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, OnClickListener {



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.Auswahl)
        ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.planets_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        ).also { adapter ->
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
            val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.Auswahl)
            spinner.onItemSelectedListener = this
            spinner.adapter = adapter
        }

        rbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        ChangeBTN.setOnClickListener(this)
    }
    

    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>, view: View?, pos: Int, id: Long) {

        var Text: String = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();

        if (Text == "Starcong") {
            A = 0.06
            G = 6.0
        }else if (Text == "Basic") {
            A = 0.09
            G = 3.0
        }else if (Text == "Prepaid") {
            A = 0.08
            G= 0.0
        } else if (Text == "Sorglos") {
            A = 1.0
            G = 0.0
        }
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {

    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        when (p0?.id) {
            R.id.rbtn -> {



                var X = XInput.text;
                var X2 = X.toString()

                var R: Double = X2.toDouble() * A + G
                ET.text = R.toString()
            }



        }
    }


}
```

and tahn this for the other Activity

```
package com.example.handytarife

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Debug
import android.text.Editable
import android.view.View
import android.view.View.OnClickListener
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnClickListener {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        rbtn.setOnClickListener(this);
        ChangeBTN.setOnClickListener(this)

    }

    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {
        when (p0?.id) {
            R.id.rbtn -> {

                var X = XInput.text;
                 var X2 = X.toString()
                 var A = KInput.text.toString();
                 var G = GInput.text.toString();
                 var R: Double = X2.toDouble() * A.toDouble() + G.toDouble()
                 ET.text = R.toString()
            }

            R.id.ChangeBTN -> {
                val Vor = Intent(this, VorlageTarif::class.java)
                startActivity(Vor)
                finish()
            }

        }

    }




    }
```

they dont show any error but then i start my Apllication and press the Button to switch my Activity then it closing itself. I tried to lock at the Internet but dont find an Answer, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your `VorlageTerif` activity class is attempted be be opened (via `Intent`) without passing both doubles (A and G) parameters that your activity requires.

Replace this in MainActivity:...

```
val vor = Intent(this, VorlageTarif::class.java)
startActivity(Vor)
```

...with this:

```
// Make sure your variable name does not start with an uppercase letter
val vor = Intent(this, VorlageTarif::class.java)
startActivity(vor)
    .putExtra(VorlageTerif.A, A.toDouble()))
    .putExtra(VorlageTerif.G, G.toDouble()))
// Pass the double variables you want in this case it would be A and G variables initialized in MainActivity, make sure to convert them to double instead of a string!
```

Without giving your second activity it's required data (in this case, a null parameter), the app will crash as a result when the null data is being used for calculations, even when there is no clear data present. This may not throw an error, just like in your case.